# set-aduser takes too long

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have written a script to update a lot of users in Active Directory.  It is taking about 10 seconds to run the update, and that seems like too long.

Here is my command:

```
Set-ADUser $userName -StreetAddress $address1 -Server "MyWickedCoolServerName"
```

I also tried something like this:

```
Set-ADUser $userName –Replace @{st=$address1} -Server "MyWickedCoolServerName"
```

As you can see I have to specify the server each time since we don't have the default one set up, could this be causing the issue?  Also, I am running this script remotely on my pc which is not on the domain, so I have to use "runas" to run powershell and have access to AD. Could that be causing the issue?

Any suggestions on what I can look at to see where the performance issue is?

Answer (score 1):

Your command will not work, because your computer is not joined to the Active Directory domain. Since you said that your computer is not domain-joined, you will have to use the `-Credential` parameter of the `Set-ADUser` command in order to run it successfully.

```
 $Credential = Get-Credential;
 Set-ADUser -Identity $userName -StreetAddress $address1 -Server MyWickedCoolServerName -Credential $Credential;
```

Comment: That was not at all my question.  I did not ask if the script would work, but rather why it was so slow. FYI, I had taken proper steps to take care of the credentials issue, it wasn't relevant to the questions so I left that out.

Comment: That is a logical question, but unfortunately not an option for me at this time.